# Problema para registrar una datos Foraneo

Tags: php, html5

Les comento tengo un problema para insertar los siguientes datos y me muestra el siguientes error
y no se como solucionarlo

> Error al pagar el estacionamientoSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`condominiomelgajero`.`pagoestacionamiento`,
>   CONSTRAINT `pagoestacionamiento_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Boleta`)
>   REFERENCES `boleta` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

aqui esta funcion que se utiliza para

```
//modelo PagoEstacionamiento

    <?php

class PagoEstacionamiento
{
    private $Id;    
    private $Boleta;
    private $Estacionamiento;
    private $MesPagado;
    private $Valor;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->Id = 0;
        $this->Boleta = 0;
        $this->Estacionamiento = "";
        $this->MesPagado = "2018-01-01";
        $this->Valor = 0;
    }

    public function getId(){
      return $this->Id;
    }

    public function setId($Id){
      $this->Id = $Id;
    }

    public function getBoleta(){
      return $this->Boleta;
    }

    public function setBoleta($Boleta){
      $this->Boleta = $Boleta;
    }

    public function getEstacionamiento(){
      return $this->Estacionamiento;
    }

    public function setEstacionamiento($Estacionamiento){
      $this->Estacionamiento = $Estacionamiento;
    }

    public function getMesPagado(){
      return $this->MesPagado;
    }

    public function setMesPagado($MesPagado){
      $this->MesPagado = $MesPagado;
    }

    public function getValor(){
      return $this->Valor;
    }

    public function setValor($Valor){
      $this->Valor = $Valor;
    }
}
?>
```

//Funcion que se utiliza

```
public function PagarEstacionamiento($dto)
    {
        try
        {
            $pdo = new Conexion();
            $stm = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pagoestacionamiento(Boleta,Estacionamiento,MesPagado,Valor) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            $stm->bindParam(1,$boleta);
            $stm->bindParam(2,$estacionamiento);
            $stm->bindParam(3,$mesPagado);
            $stm->bindParam(4,$valor);
            $boleta = $dto->getBoleta();
            $estacionamiento = $dto->getEstacionamiento();
            $mesPagado = $dto->getMesPagado();
            $valor = $dto->getValor();
            $stm->execute();
            $conn = null;
        }catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo "Error al pagar el estacionamiento".$ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

//codigos para registrar

```
$dto = new PagoEstacionamiento();
$dao = new MetodosCondominio();

$mes =  $_POST['mes'];
$anio = $_POST['anio'];
$dia = '01';

$mesPagado = $mes.'-'.$anio.'-'.$dia;

$dto->setBoleta($_POST['boleta']);
$dto->setEstacionamiento($_POST['estacionamiento']);
$dto->setMesPagado($mesPagado);
$dto->setValor($_POST['valor']);

$dao->PagarEstacionamiento($dto);
```

//codigo html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Pagar Gasto Comun</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="EstacionamientoPagado.php" method="POST">  
  <label>Boleta</label>
  <input type="text" name="boleta">
  <label>Mes</label>
  <select name="mes">
   <option value="01">Enero</option>
   <option value="02">Febrero</option>
   <option value="03">Marzo</option>
   <option value="04">Abril</option>
   <option value="05">Mayo</option>
   <option value="06">Junio</option>
   <option value="07">Julio</option>
   <option value="08">Agosto</option>
   <option value="09">Septiembre</option>
   <option value="10">Octubre</option>
   <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
   <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
  </select>
  <label>Año</label>
  <input type="text" name="anio">
  <label>Valor</label>
  <input type="text" name="valor">
  <label>Estacionamiento</label>
  <input type="text" name="estacionamiento">
  <button class="btn btn-primary block"/>Pagar Estacionamiento</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cuando haces la conexion, vinculas primero variables que no existen y luego las defines. Pon antes de la creacion de $pdo la definicion de $boleta, $estacionamiento, $mesPagado y $valor.

Comment: ¿Verificaste que el insert lo hagas en las tablas que tienes relacionadas? Seguramente tienes relaciones de tablas con campos no nulos.

Comment: Si verifique los insert de las 2 tablas y me funcionan